# Why does my GNOME dock shrinks on opening too may application?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, dash-to-dock

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with the default desktop environment (GNOME).

I installed Dash to Dock and enabled a setting (scroll to change workspace from the dock) using `dconf`. I reverted it back to the default setting, but I am now getting this new behavior where my dock size keeps changing (shrinking) when opening too many applications (see the following GIF). Before this, I was able to scroll through the list of opened applications in the dock.

[image: GIF showing dock shrinking]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Dash to Dock settings and in the *Position and size* tab check the *Fixed icon size: scroll to reveal other icons* option (see screenshot).

[image: dash to dock settings]

Note that with this option enabled, scrolling on the dock to switch workspaces will only work if you place your cursor on the applications menu icon (nine dots icon).

Comment: Thankyou So much helping, you fixed the problem.
one query though.. the app indicators shifted to bottom of app icons instead of default left side of the app after enabling the option "shrink the dash". I did disable that option to revert those app indicators, but they are still positioned at the bottom of the app. Any fixes? Thanks

Comment: Hey @user3140225 I figured out the solution, just set the value of the running app indicator to the default in dconf editor. Thanks anyways. Just letting you know about this to save your time.

Comment: @BarryBarab You're welcome! I am not able to reproduce your indicator position problem, but good to know that you've solved that too. In general, restarting GNOME Shell with `Alt`+`F2`, entering `r` and pressing `Enter` sometimes helps with such extension problems.